# saving the results of an ibaction

Tags: objective-c, ibaction

right now when you press a button, it creates a new button in a different view controller. But then when you go away from that view controller and go back, the button that was created is gone. How would I go about saving that button so that it would always be there??
Thank you.

```
- (IBAction)doneTextField:(id)sender {

       YourShortcutsViewController *YSVC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
        YSVC2.stringFromTextField = self.textField.text;
        [self presentViewController:YSVC2 animated:YES completion:nil];

        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(15, 82, 85, 85);
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(newButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatsapp_social_circle-128.png"];
        UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatsapp_social_circle-128.png"];
        UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [YSVC2 addFaceTimeButton:btn];

    }

    - (void)newButtonClicked
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:9999999999"]];


    }


    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        return [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Comment: how do you display the viewController because if you do it modally I think it will keep your interface state

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you create a new instance of the view controller each and every time you click the button.

#### This Makes a New View Controller Each and Every Time:

```
YourShortcutsViewController *YSVC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"]
```

If you need to keep the look of `YSVC2`, then you need to keep a reference to that exact instance.

You can change `YSVC2` to be a property, you can turn `YourShortcutsViewController` into a singleton, you can create a `YourShortcutsViewController` property in some common code (like the app delegate)… There are really lots of ways to solve this problem.

Comment: will this also make the buttons that were added appear after the app is closed and re-opened?

Comment: could you please give me the code I was use to do that? I am a beginner. Thank you

Comment: @user2991787 Sorry, I can't tell you what solution will work for you, because I don't know what your application needs. You will find lots of examples online for how to create a singleton (if that's what works), or how to use properties (if that's what works for you).